# transorm grids of points from world coordinates to voxel coordinates and extract the image values

Tags: matlab

I have  two rectangular grids of points (given in world coordinates): grid1 and grid2. Each grid is given as follows: 'gridn_x' is the matrix of x coordinates, 'gridn_y' is the matrix of y coordinates, 'gridn_z' is the matrix of z coordinates (all world coordinates). ALL these grids have 905x745 dimension.

I need to transfom these points from world coordinates to voxel coordinates, such that you obtain 'gridn_x_voxel', 'gridn_y_voxel',  'gridn_z_voxel'

Now that the grids are transformed in voxel coordinates, i have to extract the image values from 'data' using 'nearest', 'linear' and 'cubic' interpolation and display them.

i need these functions: figure, subplot, imshow, reshape, size, inv, interp3, tic, toc

Can someone help me please???.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/08/28/introduction-to-spatial-referencing/

I'd look at the following blog post. If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, this should walk you through most/all of what you are looking for. The workflow is to use imref3d to manage conversions from the world to the intrinsic (voxel) coordinate system. The blog post also shows how these intrinsic coordinates can be passed to MATLAB interpolation routines like interp2/interp3.